# How can I bind listbox with hashtable in ASP.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am belinda. I have tried the following cod to bind the `hashtable` with `listbox`.

***.aspx:***

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Hashtable.aspx.vb" Inherits="Hashtable" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox><br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***.aspx.vb:***

```
#Region "Namespaces"

Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail

#End Region
Partial Class Hashtable
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ht As New Hashtable
        ht.Items.Add("1", "Sunday")
        ht.Items.Add("2", "Monday")
        ht.Items.Add("3", "Tuesday")
        ht.Items.Add("4", "Wednesday")
        ht.Items.Add("5", "Thursday")
        ht.Items.Add("6", "Friday")
        ht.Items.Add("7", "Saturday")

        ListBox1.DataSource = ht
        ListBox1.DataValueField = "Key"
        ListBox1.DataTextField = "Value"
        ListBox1.DataBind()


    End Sub
End Class
```

when executing i got the following error:

```
Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
```

why this coming... and What i should do... I dont want to use dictionary and all only the `hashtable`.

am using vb.net as a language not c#
Anyone please help me and Please clear my doubt .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Dictionary instead of a hashtable? This is a even better solution as the values you add have an unique key (which is not the case in hashtables) and your values will be strongly typed:

```
#Region "Namespaces"

Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail

#End Region
Partial Class Hashtable
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        dictionary.Add(1, "Sunday")
        dictionary.Add(2, "Monday")
        dictionary.Add(3, "Tuesday")
        dictionary.Add(4, "Wednesday")
        dictionary.Add(5, "Thursday")
        dictionary.Add(6, "Friday")
        dictionary.Add(7, "Saturday")

        ListBox1.DataSource = dictionary
        ListBox1.DataBind()


    End Sub
End Class
```

Not all types of collections are supported by the `DataSource` property. While Hashtable is not supported, a Dictionary is.